# Jquery stopped loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am no java script developer but I use java script here and there so forgive if my problem is obvious.

My drop down menu stopped working I believe it have to do for bootstrap not loading  my jquery file any more.Errors I am getting:

```
> jquery-ui.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
> status of 404 (NOT FOUND) bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught
> Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
>     at bootstrap.min.js:6
>     at bootstrap.min.js:6
>     at bootstrap.min.js:6 jquery-ui.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

So those files I am loading

```
      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>




    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>


   <!-- toggle visibility for filter -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                      $("#extra-content").hide();
                      $("#toggle-content").click(function(){
                          $("#extra-content").toggle();
                      });
                  });
     </script>

      <!-- ADDING DATEPICKER FUNCTIONALITY TO ALL DATES FIELDS  -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.datetimeinput').datepicker({ format: "yyyy/mm/dd" });
            }); 
     </script>

  <!-- HIDE DISPLAY TREE BRACH WHEN CLICKED ON HEAD ITEM -->
     <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('label.tree-toggler').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(300);
                });
              });
     </script>

  <!-- I DONT REMEBER WHAT IT IS AND IF IS STILL REQUIRED  FIX -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".close").click(function(){
                  $(".alert").alert();
              });
          });  
     </script>


<!-- WAS FOR MAIN NAV  MENU SHOULD BE OR FIXED OR REPLACED WITH DJANGO TEMPLATE SELECTION  FIX -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
          $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function (e) {
          $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          });
      </script>
```

What could be the problem . This setup worked for me before for very long time but just stopped.

Comment: It looks like that file is not found. Can you check in the directory if the file still exists?

Comment: @Praveen what file you talking about the bootstrap it self? I am loading it from here  https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Boris, did you add jQuery? You **need** to include jQuery separately. It's just jQueryUI.css. No worries.

Comment: @Praveen - Yes it is there look how files with all js includes looks like. I updated it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are working offline (without a server) and I see the protocol missing from your CDNs `//code` should be changed to `https://code`.

Bootstrap CDN used had updated versions. Need to revert back to version 3.x

Comment: Nope it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try removing the `<script>` tags that have the src as `{{ STATIC_URL }}`. There isn't a need for them.

Comment: The CDN for bootstrap might be causing the issue. Maybe try and change that CDN link for bootstrap 4 to use bootstrap 3. That link may have updated to version 4 without you knowing. https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: yes so basically 2 ways to fix it - one to include the pooper link per what sugested by bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start or to use CDN link as you sugested